# Creating a block; "the options do not exist"

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

Working on a project using Symfony and the CMF bundle. I followed the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/block/create_your_own_blocks.html) in creating your own block.

However, when rendering the block, Symfony throws an exception telling me that the specified options do not exist.

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The options "title", "url" do not exist. Known options are: "attr", "extra_cache_keys", "template", "ttl", "use_cache"") in FooMainBundle::Page/Standard.html.twig at line 15.
```

This is my template (Standard.html.twig):

```
{% extends "FooMainBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ sonata_block_render({'name': 'rssBlock'}, {
        'title': 'Symfony CMF news',
        'url': 'http://cmf.symfony.com/news.rss'
    }) }}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my Document:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\BarContentBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\Annotations as PHPCR;

use Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\BlockBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\AbstractBlock;

/**
 * @PHPCR\Document(referenceable=true)
 */
class RssBlock extends AbstractBlock
{
    /**
     * @PHPCR\String(nullable=true)
     */
    private $feedUrl;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\String()
     */
    private $title;

    public function getType()
    {
        return 'foo_barcontent.block.rss';
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        $options = array(
            'title' => $this->title,
        );
        if ($this->feedUrl) {
            $options['url'] = $this->feedUrl;
        }

        return $options;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getFeedUrl() {
        return $this->feedUrl;
    }

    public function setFeedUrl($feedUrl) {
        $this->feedUrl = $feedUrl;
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;

class RssBlockService extends BaseBlockService
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Rss Reader';
    }

    /**
     * Define valid options for a block of this type.
     */
    public function setDefaultSettings(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'url'      => false,
            'title'    => 'Feed items',
            'template' => 'FooBarContentBundle:Block:block_rss.html.twig',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * The block context knows the default settings, but they can be
     * overwritten in the call to render the block.
     */
    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
    {
        $block = $blockContext->getBlock();

        if (!$block->getEnabled()) {
            return new Response();
        }

        // merge settings with those of the concrete block being rendered
        $settings = $blockContext->getSettings();
        $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
        $resolver->setDefaults($settings);
        $settings = $resolver->resolve($block->getOptions());

        $feeds = false;
        if ($settings['url']) {
            $options = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'user_agent' => 'Sonata/RSS Reader',
                    'timeout' => 2,
                )
            );

            // retrieve contents with a specific stream context to avoid php errors
            $content = @file_get_contents($settings['url'], false, stream_context_create($options));

            if ($content) {
                // generate a simple xml element
                try {
                    $feeds = new \SimpleXMLElement($content);
                    $feeds = $feeds->channel->item;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // silently fail error
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->renderResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), array(
            'feeds'     => $feeds,
            'block'     => $blockContext->getBlock(),
            'settings'  => $settings
        ), $response);
    }

    // These methods are required by the sonata block service interface.
    // They are not used in the CMF. To edit, create a symfony form or
    // a sonata admin.

    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
    {
        throw new \Exception();
    }

    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block)
    {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
}
```

And I placed this in my services.xml:

```
<service id="foo_barcontent.block.rss" class="Foo\BarBundle\Block\RssBlockService">
    <tag name="sonata.block" />

    <argument>foo_barcontent.block.rss</argument>
    <argument type="service" id="templating" />
</service>
```

Comment: Did you see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/block/types.html#rssblock ?

Comment: Several years later: Did you ever find the solution to this? I now find myself with a similar problem.